# Publish Android App in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017, according to this guide
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/visual-studio-xa-4.2.6-to-6.1/

I should be able to find the "Publish Android App" in "Tools" > "Android" menu

but I can't see that option. I try to google around and found nothing relevant.

can anyone give me some hints? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Publish Android App" is removed and replaced by "Archives".

At the Solution Explorer, right click on the project name > Archieve > Distribution